# Face not recognized in UV Editing

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I modeled this wall and want to give the sides the same wood texture as the outline. But when I select the faces of the sides they don't show up in the UV Editing window.
What am I doing wrong? Why do the side faces not get recognized?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Verts don't show up in the UV editor-- only *face corners*, per-face attributes, have UV.  Select some faces.  Or, set "sync" in UV editor.

Comment: the fact that you have all four vertices selected but the face doesn't show as selected suggests to me that you have bad geometry, probably duplicate vertices.  Have you tried selecting all the vertices and merging by distance?

Comment: It may be that the UV for the frame is far away from the center of the image (out in space), or possibly that it was never unwrapped, or that the UV map the material is using is not the one being edited in the UV editor. Check for multiple UV maps in the mesh data Properties tab.